# How to add double-quotation to s3 bucket path with in a .tsv file using sed/awk in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have `.tsv` file which contains the source and destination information of s3 bucket. I am using while loop to read source and destination path from that file and perform `s3 cp` operation. Please be informed that the file contains 100K lines.

How can I make use of `sed` command so all the source and destination paths become double-quoted within the file (`xx.tsv`). I need the double quote because aws s3 cannot handle file/folder name that has white space in it without enclosing them with `""`.

I am looking for something like below 3 lines will be changed

```
s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png
s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png
s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png
```

to

```
"s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png" "s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png" "s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png" "s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='"\t"' '{print "\"" $1, $2 "\""}' file
"s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png"
```

The above assumes that none of your file names contain tab, newline, or double quote.

Comment: this awk command was able to put a double quote on my source and destination bucket path. But when I trigger my script using Jenkins job it put a single quote in all spaces. 
`'"data02/personalis/2020/1143_TP53_retrospective/Symphony_0330_2020_TP53_PCYC_1143-1623-001_1143-1623-902_SZA7969_5644/1143-1623-001_1143-1623-902/QC_REPORT/static/common/images/header-background' 'copy.jpg"' '"s3://grc-bioinformatics-ssf-imbruvica-data01-prod/Clinical/PCYC/test/Assays/DNASeq/Personalis/ACE_Cancer_DNA_RNA_Panel/qc_report/1143-1623-001_1143-1623-902/static/common/images/header-background' 'copy.jpg"'`

Comment: I don't know what "Jenkins job" is or how that affects anything, you asked for a solution tagged with bash and awk so that's what I provided. There's nothing in my solution that adds single quotes anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your solution though which is absolutely correct and nothing to do with the Jenkins. I have noticed that it was with the bash shell. My issue has been solved just enclosing the aws s3 cp command with in bash -c command. 

`bash -c "aws s3 cp $SOURCE $DESTINATION &>> $LOG"`

Answer (score 0):

There's many way to peel that potato, but mine would be

```
sed 's;^\(s3://.*\) \(s3://.*\)$;"\1" "\2";' filename_in.tsv > out.tsv
```

which uses `sed` to apply a regular expression on the input, capturing all the "not the space between s3-URLs" parts of the string, and then putting them into quotation marks.

I hope whoever wrote the tooling that generated the .tsv learns something from this – this could also have gone irretrivably wrong, if there was newlines in the file names, for example, which is perfectly legal for file names (might not be on S3, haven't checked).

Storing filenames in "whatever-delimited" files is going to end badly (unless that delimiter is a 0-byte, which is pretty much the only forbidden byte in file names). You need escaping, or even better, don't store long lists of file names in text files, but use something simple to use as sqlite.

Comment: I don't know what version of sed you're using, but this doesn't work at all.   Even replacing the `\b+` with `\t+` doesn't fix it (note: even in versions of sed that understand \b, \b is a zero-width word-boundary assertion, not a countable pattern, so `\b+` makes no sense).    The only way I got it to work was to rewrite it to use `sed -E` for extended regular expressions: `sed -E 's;^(s3://.*)\t+(s3://.*)$;"\1"\t"\2";'` (the input is tab-separated, so the output should be too).  Or, slightly simpler: `sed -E 's/^(s3:.*)\t+(s3:.*)/"\1"\t"\2"/'`

Comment: @Marcus I am using sed version 4.4 and your regular expression did not work for me either. Even if I tried with adding -E option but no luck!

Comment: @cas the command sed -E 's/^(s3:.*)\t+(s3:.*)/"\1"\t"\2"/' test.tsv didn't work for me either.

Comment: is your text actually tab separated?  if not, try it with `\s+` or `[[:blank:]]+` instead of `\t+` - it worked for me when I tested it against your sample data (with a tab separating the columns).  I'm using GNU sed 4.8, but there's nothing in the sed script that wouldn't work with much earlier versions, should work with any version that supports the `-E` option (which was added to GNU sed a long time ago).

Comment: or you could use awk.  e.g. `awk -F'\t' '{print "\"" $1 "\"\t\"" $2 "\""}' input.tsv`

Comment: @cas I swear it worked yesterday evening... gimme a second

Comment: @cas, hm that must have been a combination of tired me mixing two approaches I've tried. just replace `\b+` with ` ` (I used the test text as copy-n-pasted from the web site)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input.tsv 
s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png     s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png
s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png     s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png
s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png     s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png
```

Note: the columns are separated by a tab character, not multiple spaces.

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(s3:.*)\t+(s3:.*)/"\1"\t"\2"/' input.tsv 
"s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png"
```

Using `\s+` or `[[:blank:]]+` between the two capture groups instead of `\t` works too, and produces identical output.  i.e.

```
sed -E 's/^(s3:.*)[[:blank:]]+(s3:.*)/"\1"\t"\2"/' input.tsv
```

and

```
sed -E 's/^(s3:.*)\s+(s3:.*)/"\1"\t"\2"/' input.tsv
```

The `[[:blank:]]+` version will match one-or-more space or tab characters as the column separator, while the `\s+` version will match one-or-more of **any** whitespace character (which includes spaces, tabs, and more).

with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print "\"" $1 "\"\t\"" $2 "\""}' input.tsv 
"s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png"
```

Comment: This command was able to put a double quote on my source and destination bucket path. But when I trigger my script using Jenkins job it put a single quote in all white/tab spaces and that is why s3 cp command is not working. it is saying "Unknown options:"

Comment: Sounds like jenkins has complicated quoting requirements of its own.  Try writing them as standalone script files and running them with `sed -f` or `awk -f` (or as executable scripts with `#!/bin/sed -f` or `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`) rather than as one-liners. Or write the entire job script in awk or perl rather than a mix of sh and sed or sh and awk.   Both awk and perl have no problem calling external programs like `cp` just like sh can (and perl also has a [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy) core library module that can copy files without forking `cp`).

Answer (score 0):

Treating the data as a CSV file that uses tabs for field delimiters:

```bsh
csvformat -tT -U1 file.tsv >newfile.tsv
```

This uses `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read the tab-delimited input (`-t`) and produces tab-delimited output (`-T`) which is quoted (`-U1`) no matter whether the CSV format requires it or not.

Treating the file as a CSV file and using a CSV parser to do the quoting for you has the benefit of not quoting fields doubly if they are already quoted.

```bsh
$ cat file.tsv
"s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png"   s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png
s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png     s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png
s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png     s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png
```

```bsh
$ csvformat -tT -U1 file.tsv
"s3://data01/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata01/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data02/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata02/vol01/image live01.png"
"s3://data03/repo01/image live01.png"   "s3://Ata03/vol01/image live01.png"
```

---

You could also obviously just read the data as it is and add the double quotes when you call `s3 cp`.  I don't know what that command looks like but...

```bsh
while IFS=$'\t' read -r src dst; do
    s3 cp "\"$src\"" "\"$dst\""
done <file.tsv
```